# Assigning pointer from strtok to pointer in 2d array of structs all entries should be unique but print out as identical

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, strtok

Assigning pointer from `strtok()` to  `ptr` contained within a struct. I have a 2d array of these structs that I want to use to store the data I'm trying to parse from a csv file.

```
typedef struct Entry 
{
    char *str;
} Entry;
```

I'm taking output from `fgets()` and sending it through my own function `TokenizeLine()` in order to split it up and assign it to the proper locations in the array. However every pointer in every entry of my 2d array (`etable`) ends up holding the same value.

What is the issue with the below code?

```
fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn);

while (currentLineStr[0] == '#')
      fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn);

TokenizeLine(currentLineStr, eTable, yIndex, x, y);
yIndex++;

while(fgets(currentLineStr, 8192, fileIn) != NULL)
{
      TokenizeLine(currentLineStr, eTable, yIndex, x, y);
      yIndex++;
} 



void TokenizeLine(int x; int y; char currentLineStr[], Entry eTable[x][y], int yIndex, int x, int y)
{
      char *tokPtr;
      int xIndex = 0;

      tokPtr = strtok(currentLineStr, "|");

      while(tokPtr != NULL)
      {
            eTable[xIndex][yIndex].str = tokPtr;
            tokPtr = strtok(NULL, "|");      
            xIndex++;
      } 
 }
```

Comment: Please post compilable code and show the definition of eTable.

Comment: You're reusing `currentLineStr` for all strings, overwriting its contents by `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, all the `str`s are essentially working as a *placeholder* for the `tokPtr`. All of them point to only `tokPtr`. Now, after finishing the `while()` loop, the latest value held by `tokPtr` will also be ponteed by *all* the `str`s.

To avoid, you need to

1. Allocate memory to each `str`, maybe using `malloc()`.
2. Use `strcpy()` to *copy* the current value of `tokPtr` into corresponding `str`.

Comment: So if I understand correctly assign memory to `str` using         `malloc(sizeof tokPtr )` ? then copy value of tokPtr using              `strcpy(str, tokPtr)` ?

Comment: @J2R5M3 not `sizeof`, use `malloc( strlen(tokPtr) + 1)`

Comment: This answer is misleading because it suggests that every `str` points at the same token, but the OP's code doesn't do that. strtok returns pointers into the string you gave it, but it won't return the same pointer twice for a particular input.

Answer (score 0):

As EOF wrote in a comment, you reuse the buffer `currentLineStr`. Each time you call `fgets`, you're overwriting the storage used for *all the previous lines*, including the memory pointed to by every `str`. This is because `strtok` returns pointers into the string that you first gave it.

Sourav Ghosh's solution works because it copies each token from the shared buffer as it is encountered (returning a pointer to the copy). Another solution that would also work is to `malloc()` the space for `currentLineStr` inside the loop where you call `fgets()`.

As an aside, I recommend that you don't do this:

```
typedef struct Entry {...} Entry;
```

C++ is another language. Either don't use the typedef and call it "struct Entry", or typedef it without a struct tag:

```
typedef struct {...} Entry;
```

There is a convention in the C standard library that typedef names end in _t, so you could also do something like this (or choose a naming convention that makes sense to you):

```
typedef struct Entry {...} Entry_t;
```